# Run Tr.launcher without NavBar Work Center

Tags: abap, sap-crm

I created the following custom objects and customizing:

- Z program
- Z transaction, which runs the Z program
- Transaction Launcher, which runs the Z transaction (Enterprise Portal or ITS?)
- Logical Link, which runs the Transaction Launcher
- Workcenter, which runs the Logical Link
- Navigation Bar Profile, whom the Workcenter is assigned to
- Button in Web UI, which runs the Logical Link

Currently, pressing the button starts the Z program successfully.

But if I delete the Workcenter from the Navigation Bar Profile, my button doesn't work anymore.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Could you improve your question so that it's more readable by future visitors, according to stackoverflow rules, please? (cf Help center)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Logical Link can be called only if it's assigned to one element in the customizing (transaction code `CRMC_UI_NBLINKS`). If your logical link is not attached to any element of the CRM UI Framework, i.e. it's called from ABAP code (called from a button in a Web UI component), you may choose to assign it to a "Generic Outbound Plug". For example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sandra.
Is there any way to hide that work center?
Because I'm not sure will it works or not.

Comment: And can you explain me what's WRAPPED PFCG and CT-BR-PFCG?
And how should I apply it in my case?

Comment: The workcenter you removed from the profile is still shown, how come? I answered that you don't need to assign a logical link to a workcenter. WRAPPED_PFCG is the name of a UI object type (the one which corresponds to the Web UI component). CT-BR-PFCG is the name of a logical link. Replace these values with your own objects.

Comment: I removed work center from my NavBar and now it is not shown anymore. Can you tell me, please, how can I define it (UI object type (the one which corresponds to the Web UI component)) for my case?

Comment: I'm not sure whether the UI object type has any importance here. Just choose one which corresponds to the object you work with in your UI component. What is important is that when the user logs in the Web Client, the system will make an internal list of all logical links defined in the user's navigation profile, and therefore you'll be able to run the logical link from your ABAP program (`cl_crm_ui_navigation_service=>get_instance( )->navigate( ... )`).

Comment: PS: I made lots of assumptions because you didn't give any information in your initial question; that would be nice if you could explain how you connect the button to the logical link and so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sandra. Your advice helped to me for solve my problem.

Comment: Fine. Remember that stackoverflow is not a classic forum, it's for providing answers to precise questions, not a help forum i.e. its goal is not to help only the original poster but mainly all future visitors. I propose to rewrite the question, and at the same time, that would be nice if you could post an "Answer" how you solved your problem. Thank you.